# Can std::mutex be used from a non std::thread?

Tags: c++11

Can std::mutex be used from a non std::thread like a regular pthread ? So no header `<thread>` is included.

Comment: Yes it can, otherwise it would be impossible to use it from the *main* thread the process is running (the one `main` was called in). Is there a reason you don't want to use `std::thread`?

Comment: Thanks I didn't think of the main thread. std::thread makes my Android application crash (using g++4.8). I didn't test std::mutex yet though.